# Angular reactive forms making object when I only want to pass a string (ANGULAR 5 AND FIREBASE)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, angular-reactive-forms

So I am creating a form where people can upload a profile picture to firebase. I want it to upload like `profile_image_url: 'urlstringvalue'`. However it is uploading like so:

[image]

This is how I am creating the form :

```
  ngOnInit() {
this.signUpFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
  profile_image_url: ''
});
```

}
and the html:

```
<form [formGroup]="signUpFormGroup">
            <div class="form_input" >
              <label for="invoice-upload" class="bold-800 document-upload text-center"
                     *ngIf="!signUpFormGroup.get('profile_image_url').value">+<br>
                <div class="upload text-center">upload</div>
                <input formGroupName="profile_image_url"  (change)="uploadProfileImage($event)" type="file" class="input-file" id="invoice-upload">
              </label>
              <img
                [src]="signUpFormGroup.get('profile_image_url').value" alt="" class="document-image">
            </div>
          </form>
```

I am storing the url like so:

```
  uploadProfileImage(file) {
    this._storage.uploadFile(file, `user/${this._auth.currentUserId}/profile`)
      .subscribe(() => {
        this._storage.downloadURL.subscribe(url => {
          this.signUpFormGroup.get('profile_image_url').patchValue(url);
        });
      });
  }
```

and then finally uploading to firebase database as follows:

```
setProfileImageAndGender(profile_image_url: string) {
    return fromPromise(this.afs.collection('users').doc(this.userDb.uid)
      .update({
         profile_image_url,
      }, ));
  }
```

Anyone have any idea why it is creating the object and not just passing the string?

Comment: Currently you are getting URL string value right. do you require Base64 content?

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya Yes I do, and no I do not

Comment: well, your way is not reactive, in component you have described angular form with fields, in htm you should apply name of filed from your formgroup, i propose you to move the url data outside fromGroup right to your component, see more examples on Angular official docs

`<form [formGroup]="profileForm">
  
  <label>
    First Name:
    <input type="text" formControlName="firstName">
  </label>

  <label>
    Last Name:
    <input type="text" formControlName="lastName">
  </label>

</form>`